# GNU Radio head block doesn't finish simulation

Tags: gnuradio

My task is to generate finite number of samples and save it to the file. For that purpose I used **head** block but after setting the run option to: *Run to Completion*, the flowgraph doesn't stop, just hanging. Any idea how to force my flowgraph to stop after certain amount of samples is written to the file?

[image]

Comment: If you're writing stuff into a file, anyway, the Throttle block does nothing useful.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for a useful information! But removing throttle block didn't help solve the problem

Comment: Can you try to replace the constellation modulator with a packed-to-unpacked (converting 8bit bytes to bytes in which only 1 bit is set)-> chunks to symbols (giving you 0,1->+1,-1)->root raised cosine filter?

Comment: @MarcusMüller After assembling modulator like you said, saving to the file works like a charm! Do you think that this issue has to be reported?

Comment: I haven't checked, but I think constellation modulator is deprecated already.

Comment: @MarcusMüller so what is going to replace the constellation modulator block?

Comment: Nothing probably. It's not that useful, if a relatively logical chain of blocks can replace it and let the user know exactly what is happening inside. But I was wrong, it's not deprecated.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ok, thanks for help ;)